# complex datatype in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, data-structures, complex-data-types

i need some help for my problem related to complex datatype in C#. I have following type of data and i want to save it in variable, but it will be performance efficient as i have to use it for search and there will be lot of data in it. Data sample is as follow:

```
ParentNode1
           ChildNode1
           ChildNode2
           ChildNode3
ParentNode2
ParentNode3
ParentNode4
           ChildNode1
           ChildNode2
                     Node1
                     Node2
                     Node3
                          Nth level Node1
           ChildNode3
ParentNode5
```

Above data is just a sample to show hierarchy of data. I'm not sure nested List, Dictionary, ienumerable or link list which will be best related to performance. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell what exactly are you going to search for? It is very important when it comes to efficiency in data structures.

Comment: thanks for reply. These nodes will be of type string and i will search string in them, using contains() or regex

Comment: Is `parent-child` relationship defined beforehand for the nodes?

Comment: yes, there relation must be there logically implemented by DataType. As when i get some data from some node, i need its parent node details too.

Comment: Should there be any additional constraint related to the hierarchy for searching? I mean *look for nodes being childs of a given node and containing ...*.

Comment: yes, i will run code foreach loop to search for item contained in Nth node. and if it will be found then i will get its parent information. like complete parent string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that a search will take place at a single level, then you might want a list of lists: one list for each level. If your hierarchy has N levels, then you have N lists. Each one contains nodes that are:

```
ListNode
    Data // string
    ParentIndex // index of parent in the previous list
```

So to search level 4, you go to the list for that level and do your `contains` or regex test on each node in that level. If it matches, then the `ParentIndex` value will get you the parent, and its `ParentIndex` will get you the grandparent, etc.

This way, you don't have to worry about navigating the hierarchy except when you find a match, and you don't have to write nested or recursive algorithms to traverse the tree.

You could maintain your hierarchy, as well, with each top-level node containing a list of child nodes, and build this secondary list only for searching.